# Django / postgresql 'column "type_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer'

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have an Django app that is working locally, but when I try to deploy it to production it fails with the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "type_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING type_id::integer".
```

The main difference between my local setup and production is that I am using SQLite3 and production is using postgres

The migration it fails on is migration 10, which looks like this.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('speakers', '0009_auto_20180117_1335'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='speaker',
            name='type',
            field=models.ForeignKey(to='speakers.Type'),
        ),
    ]
```

The preceding migration, its dependency and the last working migration look like this:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('speakers', '0008_auto_20180117_1309'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Type',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=200)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Type',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'Types',
            },
        ),
        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='speaker',
            old_name='speaker_categories',
            new_name='type',
        ),
    ]
```

To make things I'll also include the models (as they look at the end)

```
class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Type")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Types")



class Speaker(models.Model):

    VIDEO_SRC_TYPES = (
        ('yt', 'Youtube'),
        ('vm', 'Vimeo'),
    )

    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        choices=STATUSES,
        verbose_name=_("Status"),
        default=DEFAULT_STATE)

    type = models.ManyToManyField(Type)
```

(most fields from the 'Speaker' model have been removed to keep the code short)

I suspect the problem is due some difference between SQLite and postgres, which is causing the migrations to run on SQLITE and crash on postgres. But I am not very knowledgable in the specifics of databases, and I have no idea where to go from here. Does anyone have an idea of what is happening and how to solve this problem?  Any help would be very appreciated as our team is currently very stuck

Specs:

Python: python2.7 . (yeah I know, but its an old app)

DB production: postgres

DB local: sqlite

Comment: what is your python version? and can you post the SlugModel

Comment: thanks for your response! Its python2.7, I've added it in the post. I've also removed the reference in the slugmodel in the post - it would complicate the code but doesn't do anything with any relevant fields. Thanks for helping correct these oversights!

Comment: the easiest way will be to delete the migration files you have and run migrate in the server again, its better not to use local migrations files when in production

Comment: The server logs show that it all worked up untill migration 10. Does this mean that all migrations untill migration 10 have been applied? (And thus meaning that I can no longer delete these)

Or are they reverted? (Meaning I can delete all of my local migraitons and create a new single migration)

Comment: if those are created you need to drop the database and delete all the migrations file except init.py and then run migrate

Comment: Dropping the entire database isnt an option, as it contains important data. 

The plan that we currently have is as follows: reverting back until migration 6 (the last migration that is used as a dependency by other apps within the project), creating a new migration file - and running untill this new migration file. 

This way we wont touch other tables within the database.

Comment: You should keep [development, staging, and production as similar as possible](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity).  You should be using postgreSQL locally, so then you'll catch these issues before you deploy to production(!!!)

Comment: @Exprator That is entirely incorrect - migration files are database agnostic, and should be kept in version control - DEFINITELY not regenerated upon deployment.  Suggesting someone _drop their production database_ is very dangerous.  Please do not comment if you don't know what you're doing.  :(

Comment: @AdamBarnes if you think so, be happy with it, and i told to drop the database as i thought it doesnt contain any data. as he is migrating newly

Comment: A migration is about changing the database from one state to the next.  A very small proportion of all migrations are new databases.  In an app I have open right now, the smallest amount of migrations we have is 36.  As I said, please do not comment if you don't know what you're doing - your advice, if followed, would have been catastrophic for the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your responses everyone! We've resolved the issue by making new migration files (i'll explain in more detail in the post below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've solved the problem as follows:

1. We reverted to migration 0006* - this is the last migration that migrations in other apps used as a dependency
2. We deleted all migration files above 0006*
3. We created a new migration file, that contained all of the changes.
4. We deployed to the production server

This process solved the problem.

Now about the cause of the problem, there are 2 main reasons (as pointed out by Adam Barnes in the comments below the original post)

1. We used different Databases between local and production.
2. We arent using a Local-Staging-Production setup for this project.

I've adviced my manager to change this situation ASAP, as following best practices here could have prevented this whole situation.

Thanks for your help everyone!